# Automatically create django model instances at startup with empty database

Tags: python, django, django-models

My django project requires some model instances to be created at startup if they do not exist.

I currently create the required model instances I need in an app config.

```
class MyAppConfig(AppConfig):
name = 'my_app'

def ready(self):
    create_required_objects()

def create_required_objects():
    from my_app.models import MyObject
    for name in MyObject.reserved_names:
        if not MyObject.objects.filter(name=name).exists():
            MyObject.objects.create(name=name, not_editable=True)
```

This works perfectly when the sqlite database is initialized, however if I clear the database and then try to run the sever, I get the following error:

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table: my_app_object
```

I would like to be able to clear the database (preferably by just removing db.sqlite3) and run the server.

Comment: This error comes due to the code you mentioned when you clear database and again run the server and you are importing object of `my_app.models` which is not present in the database.

Answer (score 1):

Use `post_migrate` signal to create a new instance when migrating to the new database:

Like:

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_migrate
from my_app.models import MyObject

def create_required_objects(sender, **kwargs):
    for name in MyObject.reserved_names:
       if not MyObject.objects.filter(name=name).exists():
            MyObject.objects.create(name=name, not_editable=True)
   
class MyAppConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'my_app'

def ready(self):
    post_migrate.connect(create_required_objects ,sender=self)
```

This code automatically generates the user after migrating to the database.

Comment: For more information on the post_migrate signal, you can check the doc here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/signals/#post-migrate

Comment: Note: you cannot import the models at the top of file because at this time, the project is not ready (exception raised). You must import them from the `ready(self)` method.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [model_bakery](https://github.com/model-bakers/model_bakery) to populate some temp data. You may need to do makemigrations and migrate to set up all tables in your database, you can follow [this workflow](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/migrations/#workflow).

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

In terms of populating data, you can try the following code:

```
from model_bakery import baker
from my_app.models import MyObject

baker.make(MyObject)
```

Add `baker.make(MyObject)` in your `create_required_objects` function after installation of model_bakery:
`pip install model_bakery`